# Weird interference between two DDEV projects using PostgreSQL

Tags: ddev

I am working on two Drupal (7 and 9) projects which use PostgreSQL (based on the [procedure described here](https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services/postgres)). I noticed errors when they are both running at the same time: Drupal 7 will complain the `variable` table does not exist, while Drupal 9 will disconnect me or display some kind of WSOD. Oddly enough, they can *randomly* work correctly or crash again on page reload. However, it gets perfectly fine when I turn one off.

All this makes me think of some trouble with the way I configured PostgreSQL. Could you please help me find what might be wrong in my setup?

Here is my configuration for Drupal 9. docker-compose.postgres.yaml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-postgres
    image: postgres:13.4
    ports:
      - 32784:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<REDACTED>
      - POSTGRES_USER=<REDACTED>
      - POSTGRES_DB=<REDACTED>
    volumes:
      - type: "volume"
        source: postgres
        target: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: "bind"
        source: "."
        target: "/mnt/ddev_config"
      - ddev-global-cache:/mnt/ddev-global-cache
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
  web:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres

volumes:
  postgres:
```

And settings.ddev.php:

```
<?php                                                      
                                                           
/**                                                                                                                    
 * @file                                                   
 * Manually managed.                                       
 */                                                        

$host = "postgres";                                        
$port = 5432;                                              

// If DDEV_PHP_VERSION is not set but IS_DDEV_PROJECT *is*, it means we're running (drush) on the host,
// so use the host-side bind port on docker IP
if (empty(getenv('DDEV_PHP_VERSION') && getenv('IS_DDEV_PROJECT') == 'true')) {
  $host = "127.0.0.1";                                     
  $port = -1;                                              
}                                                          

$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'database' => "<REDACTED>",                                      
  'username' => "<REDACTED>",                                      
  'password' => "<REDACTED>",                                      
  'host' => $host,                                         
  'driver' => "pgsql",                                     
  'port' => $port,                                         
  'prefix' => "",                                          
);
```

(Hash and config settings omitted.)

Now, for Drupal 7. docker-compose.postgres.yaml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-postgres
    image: mdillon/postgis:11
    ports:
      - 32785:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<REDACTED>
      - POSTGRES_USER=<REDACTED>
      - POSTGRES_DB=<REDACTED>
    volumes:
      - type: "volume"
        source: postgres
        target: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: "bind"
        source: "."
        target: "/mnt/ddev_config"
      - ddev-global-cache:/mnt/ddev-global-cache
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
  web:
    links:
      - postgres:postgres

volumes:
  postgres:
```

settings.ddev.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Manually managed.
 */

$host = "postgres";
$port = 5432;

// If DDEV_PHP_VERSION is not set but IS_DDEV_PROJECT *is*, it means we're
// running (drush) on the host, so use the host-side bind port on docker IP.
if (empty(getenv('DDEV_PHP_VERSION') && getenv('IS_DDEV_PROJECT') == 'true')) {
  $host = "127.0.0.1";
  $port = 32784;
}

$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => "<REDACTED>",
  'username' => "<REDACTED>",
  'password' => "<REDACTED>",
  'host' => $host,
  'driver' => "pgsql",
  'port' => $port,
  'prefix' => "",
];
```

I was able to check that `postgres` is actually an alias for distinct FQDN and different IPs (not very Docker Compose savvy, sorry about that).

There are two distinct volumes on my system (although I have no guarantee they are correctly used):

```
$ docker volume ls | grep postgres     
local     ddev-mgis_postgres
local     ddev-mgisv5_postgres
```

When I run `drush sqlc` from the Drupal 7 project, I see Drupal 9 tables until the other project is switched off. What a nightmare!

My biggest fear is that both projects might be sharing resources, and potentially writing in the same place at some point.

I need to be able to run both projects simultaneously, as one of them needs to be migrated to the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update for DDEV v1.19+

1. Postgres is now available of the box with DDEV, so there is no need for an additional service/container.
2. You no longer have to use an explicit name for the container, since the networking in DDEV is now more sophisticated.

--------- Original Answer Below ----------

You're using `$host = "postgres";`, please use the explicit name of the postgres container, `ddev-<project>-postgres`

The hostname `postgres` is ambiguous inside the docker network when you're running more than one project that has a service named "postgres". So you're getting the behavior you see.

A PR to the ddev-contrib recipe would be appreciated; this has been updated in lots of the ddev-contrib recipes since the problem was discovered a year or so ago, but apparently not this one.

Comment: Thanks! Pull request created: https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/pull/174